# Scale text from iPhone 7 to 7 Plus

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, size-classes

Is there a 'built-in' way to scale text between an iPhone 7 and 7 Plus? I would like the text on the 7 Plus to be larger. Size classes will not work because both devices are the same (wC hR).

I'm currently subclassing UITextView and UILabel to scale the font based on the width of the screen. I also added an `IBInspectable` so I can turn it on/off in interface builder.

```
@IBInspectable var autoScale: Bool = true { ...
```

Wondering if there is a better way that Apple recommends.

Thanks!

Comment: That's the only way I know. Apple recommends using size classes for an "adaptable UI", and "Dynamic Type" for text - but that means have the *user* choose how large they want text in all apps. I had a need for this a year ago, and I ended up doing what you did - check the screen size (usually a no-no) and set the font size from that. I've since moved a lot into an animated tool board to remove the need for that.

Comment: Why are you telling your users they cannot select their own text size? My advice - Just use Dynamic Type and let your users choose how much text to view. This is less work for you, less code to write / debug and maintain and is how iOS is supposed to work. Take advantage of Apple's work and ongoing optimisations and don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: You mean 7 and 7 Plus right?